# Tooltip with info on click

Tags: tooltip

I have been looking for something similar to the map at http://www.rottnestisland.com/. As you can see, you click on an icon then a tooltip with information comes up.

Searched for two days now for something similar but I only get the regular tooltips. Do I just edit the tooltip CSS and go from there or am I searching for the wrong thing? I just want to know if what I am looking for is indeed a tooltip or called something else?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I know that bootstrap has these things called `popover`. Take a look at this: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers. You have to style it yourself with CSS if you want it like the website you wrote in your question.

Comment: Thank you so much! I finally can move on with this feature. Now I just need to style it.  Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome :) @Carl

Answer (score -1):

Instead using the concept of tool tip we can use simply show hide in a div. In your reference link also they have used opacity in css to show hide the div (Tooltip).